# Разработать физику свободного падения объекта на c++

Tags: c++, sfml, model, моделирование

### Мне нужно написать программу, которая будет **моделировать** ситуацию:

---

Некий объект, обладающий своими физ. свойствами (масса, материал, размер, цвет, и тд) будет падать с заданной высоты N.
Программа должна исходя из физических законов *(в самом простом варианте, без замудренности)* и физических свойств объекта вернуть значения:

1. t - время, за которое этот объект упадет на землю.
2. V - скорость нач., скор. конеч., среднюю скорость.
3. ускорение свободного падения

Также надо: смоделировать силу упругости (то есть, на сколько подпрыгнет после приземления).

Все это нужно сделать графически, используя c++.
Какими средства лучше всего использовать?
SFML, OpenGL, или что-то есть более подходящее для этой цели?
И есть ли какая-либо литература по этому вопросу.
Спасибо.

Comment: Для этого достаточно стандартного ввода/вывода и учебника за ~пятый класс...

Comment: Мне надо сделать 2D графику, пространство и тд

Comment: Угу, SFML или OpenGL подойдут. Есть еще SDL. Выбираете любой и гуглите туториалы.

Comment: Можно использовать SFML для графики и Box2D для физики

Comment: Если только 2D OpenGL не нужен

Comment: имхо box2d + qml

Answer (score -1):

Из моего стека знаний это легче всего сделать в **Юнити3д**, если дозволено использовать шарп.
Начальная скорость будет 0 при этом в апдейте ему нужно задать ускорение
Это даст среднюю скорость, скорость в любой момент и данные об ускорении
Чтобы показать упругость нужно прописать обратное ускорение при касании объекта, это можно сделать в классе шара, там же можно подставить разные константы упругости и по кнопкам использовать именно их для отображения разных материалов. 
В +сах это тоже можно сделать путем приложения, но тут уже придется больше повозиться, хотя механика все та же - создать класс шара и поверхности, задать вектор движения шара и метод, который будет генерировать его в пространстве, за пол можно брать просто нижнюю границу экрана, в целом это можно сделать и без сторонних библиотек.
**В итоге имеем в любом из вариантов**

- **Класс шара со всеми примочками** ( *ускорение, обязательно публичное поле - скорость, упругость*)
- **Класс пространства** (*в нем прописуем нижнюю границу, взаимодействие ее с шаром, а также метод, который будет отвечать за соотношение высоты и отображение линейки на экране, подсчет времени в полете (от 0 до препятствия или остановки) ну и в конце метод, который будет генерировать этот шар на нужной нам высоте*)
- **Ну и пользовательский интерфейс** (*Выбор материала (константы упругости), высоты, по желанию цвета шара и кнопки старта. Далее поля, которые покажут скорость, время и ускорение для данной сессии ну и мелочи по желанию.* )
  **На этом все - удачи**

**P.S. - про момент падения шара**
Нужно задать ему постоянное ускорение (по формуле в зависимости от массы и материала) по вектору **вниз** в апдейте, который будет срабатывать скажем каждые **0.1** или **0.01** секунды, а при касании умножить **скорость** на **-1(х)**, где **х** будет отвечать за то, сколько скорости у него останется после падения, таким образом он будет подскакивать вверх, терять скорость и падать вниз, пока скорости будет достаточно для подъема.

Comment: ответ не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу, тебе же сказали С++

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, правда юнити мне не подойдет, но в любом случае очень благодарен!

Comment: Нууу, я вроде как описал все то же самое для +сов и как это сделать, какие классы, поля, методы и прочие тонкости, ибо сам подобное делал и там и там, если ты не можешь прочитать дальше 1й строчки, это не значит, что ответ не имеет отношения -_-